# /bin/sh: find: command not found in dockerfile with rockylinux:8

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have dockerfile created in os: `rockylinux:8`.
Getting error: `/bin/sh: find: command not found`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM rockylinux:8 AS builder

RUN mkdir /usr/share/dashboards
WORKDIR /usr/share/dashboards
RUN find /usr/share/dashboards
```

Error-

```
/bin/sh: find: command not found
The command '/bin/sh -c find /usr/share/dashboards' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `find` command is not included in the base rockylinux image, you have to install the `findutils` package before you can use it.

I just tested, and this works:

```
FROM rockylinux:8 AS builder

RUN yum install -y findutils
WORKDIR /usr/share/dashboards
RUN find /usr/share/dashboards
```

Now, its best practice to update the image at the beginning of your build, so you get the latest packages and security patches, so I would actually do this instead:

```
FROM rockylinux:8 AS builder

RUN yum -y update
RUN yum install -y findutils
WORKDIR /usr/share/dashboards
RUN find /usr/share/dashboards
```

And later you can optimize this by putting both yum command in the same RUN instruction, and maybe clean up the cache, but this should be enough to get you started.

PS: in their edit, @DavidMaze pointed out that the `mkdir` line in your Dockerfile is redundant, since the `WORKDIR` instruction already creates the directory.